# Can I use generics to do the same operation on similar types of controls?

Tags: delphi, generics

I am using Delphi 2010 and I have a unit where over the years I have added my own procedures and functions that can be used with any project I make, such as:

```
function ListBoxIsSelected(ListBox: TListBox): Boolean;
begin
  Result:= ListBox.ItemIndex <> -1;
end;
```

The above uses `TListBox` as a parameter, so whenever the above function is used I must supply a `listbox` that is of `TListBox` class.

Now suppose I have some other component libraries that could work with the same function, For example the Jedi component classes.

How could I use the above function, when the Jedi `listbox` is `TJvListBox` class and my function is looking for `TListBox` class? Although both components are practically the same, the class names are different. If I provided the same function specifically for the `TJvListBox` it would likely work because they are both "listboxes":

```
function ListBoxIsSelected(ListBox: TJvListBox): Boolean;
begin
  Result:= ListBox.ItemIndex <> -1;
end;
```

Now, I have whole load of procedures and functions written in the same kind of way where I need to pass a component as a parameter. Having to rewrite them again just to work with a different component class is not feasible!

How can I write this with generics?

Comment: Your examples (helper functions) seem really not very helpful.  Generics are not meant to provide you write fewer helper functions, so much as they are intended to help you write things like containers that can contain any kind of object, and things like that.

Answer (score 9):

You can't write that with generics, unless your target classes all descend from the same base class of course. (But then you wouldn't need generics for it.)

If you really want something that can check if the ItemIndex property on **any** object <> -1, though, you can do that with a different Delphi 2010 feature: extended RTTI.

```
uses
  SysUtils, RTTI;

function IsSelected(item: TObject): boolean;
var
  context: TRttiContext;
  cls: TRttiType;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  ItemIndex: integer;
begin
  if item = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('Item = nil');
  context := TRttiContext.Create;
  cls := context.GetType(item.ClassType);
  prop := cls.GetProperty('ItemIndex');
  if prop = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('Item does not contain an ItemIndex property.');
  ItemIndex := prop.GetValue(item).AsInteger;
  result := ItemIndex <> -1;
end;
```

Careful, though.  There's no compile-time type checking here, and this process is significantly slower than your original routine.  You probably won't notice it, but if you call something like this in a tight loop, it will slow it down.

Comment: +1, just one question: why not use assertions to check for nil item and ItemIndex property?  I think assertion is more suitable for that than a _generic_ Exception floating around.

Comment: @jachguate: That's another option, which I might use instead depending on how widely available this function is.  And yes, it's better to use a specific exception than to use `Exception`; this example is only intended as an example, not as actual production code.

Comment: @jachguateL because asssertions are for debugging. It is not a good idea to swap a normal exception in debug builds for an access violation in release builds as would happen above. You might choose to return false instead of an error on the basis that a non-existant property can't be "Selected", but an AV is never an acceptable result.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand how I can write this with Generics?

You can’t – not unless your component implements a common interface or inherits from a common base class with the standard `ListBox`, and that interface / base class offers the `ItemIndex` property.

In fact, this use-case isn’t such a great example of generics because using an interface or base class in the declaration would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can write two overloaded functions, one expecting TJvListBox and the other expecting TListBox.

In more complex cases this approach may not apply so well, but I think your case is simple enough for this solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (it wasn't about TListBox/TJvListBox). The question was about using generics. :)

Comment: Sounds that he can't use generics in this case. I answered to provide  an alternative, even though not in the way he was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot look it up right now (on holiday, no Delphi), but don't TJvListBox and TListBox descend from a common ancestor (my guess would be: TCustomListBox)? In that case something like this should work:

```
interface

function TListBox_IsItemSelected(_ListBox: TCustomListBox): boolean;

implementation

function TListBox_IsItemSelected(_ListBox: TCustomListBox): boolean;
begin
  Result := _ListBox.ItemIndex <> -1;
end;
```

Just in case ItemIndex (as I said: I cannot check right now) is protected in TCustomListBox, you can just use a typecast hack:

```
type
  TListBoxHack = class(TCustomListBox)
  end;

function TListBox_IsItemSelected(_ListBox: TCustomListBox): boolean;
begin
  Result := TListBoxHack(_ListBox).ItemIndex <> -1;
end;
```

(I just thought I should mention this since the original question has already been answered: Using Generics does not help here.)